# Is it possible to make material independent of the geometry or the details of the mesh?

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm trying to make mountains and apply texture. Both the ground and the top of the mountains look good. In the mesh, some faces start from the ground and end at the top so the material is scaled differently which makes it look weird. Is it possible to distribute the material uniformly regardless of the geometry or those long faces? I'm using EEVEE. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by UV stretching, which is a result of deforming the mesh with a displacement AFTER the model was already UV unwrapped.

- Open the UV Editing tab
- Hit the N key to open the side bar
- Expand the overlay section of views
- Tick the box that says Stretching

Now you will see something like this:
[image: Bad stretching]

The dark blue areas are good and have little or no stretching.  The bright areas with more yellow are bad and have a lot of stretching.   To fix it try selecting all of the UVs and hitting UV -> minimize stretch.  If this doesn't fix this issue enough, then you should try to unwrap the model again.

- NOTE - If you don't see any stretching, try applying your displacement modifier.

Comment: It works and now it looks nicer :) Thank you so much @Vega_KH for helping me. You saved me a lot of trials and effort. You're great!

Comment: No problem, glad it worked!